# A result that I can't figure out

Tags: c, integer-overflow

I've been learning C recently.
I have difficulty understanding the result of the code below.
Why is `b` 255 at last?

```
unsigned char a=1;
int b=0;
do
{
   b++;
   a++;
}while(a!=0);
```

Comment: What did you expect to happen?

Comment: Think about the values that `a` goes through on each loop iteration before it reaches 0. (Do you understand why `a` will eventually reach 0?)

Comment: To add to @BilltheLizard's comment, think specifically about the size of `a` in bits and what that means in terms of the possible numbers it can store.

Comment: @BilltheLizard Actually i don't understand.Is it about the ASCII?

Comment: @Manhooo No, this has nothing to do with ASCII. An `unsigned char` is as I explained in my answer a number between 0 and 255. ASCII is the conversion of a number between 0 and 255 (most often a `char`, signed or unsigned) to a character.

Comment: Add a print statement to print out the values of `a` and `b` if you are still having trouble.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An `unsigned char` can only take values between 0 and 255. In your code, at each iteration of the loop, `a` and `b` both get incremented by 1 until `a` reaches 255. When `a` is 255 and should be incremented by 1 more, it would have been 256 but since an `unsigned char` can only take values between 0 and 255, `a` takes the value 0 instead of 256. Then, the loop stops because of `while(a!=0)` and `b` will equal 256 - 1 = 255.